# Two bitwise strings in to one bitwise string

Tags: c++, string, binary

Edited -- See below for new info........  I'm new to programming - C++ - and was on Codingame where I ran in to a problem I can't find the answer for...

We were given two strings -- not char array which I expected and seems many of the answers I found on the web expected too -- and were expected to combine them in to one.

Example:

string1 = 01101

string2 = 01001

Answer  = 01001

I have learned and understand how the answer is derived but I can't figure out the C++ code for it.

Any help would be great!

Thank you!

---

Thanks to nicomp I now know the correct terms are bitwise AND, not binary merge.

I was able to get a little further but still having issues getting the answer.  I took the following code and got the output of 73.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 = "001101";
    string str2 = "011001";

    int a = stoi(str1);
    cout << a << endl;
    
    int b = stoi(str2);
    cout << b << endl;

    int c = a & b;
    cout << c << endl;



    return 0;

}
```

The result I should get is:

```
    string str1 = "001101";
    string str2 = "011001";

    Answer      = "001001";
```

or I would have settled for 9 since that is the non-binary value, not 73.

Can someone help me progress with this?

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: How is the answer derived? It this a bitwise AND, but with strings as input and output?

Comment: Hi Scott... sorry all I have for effort is searching the web. Maybe part of the issue is I don't have the correct terms.

Comment: Hi nicomp. Thank you! yes this is bitwise AND (the term I couldn't remember) and I was given a string for input and expected a string for output.

Comment: Note the existence of [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) which has to/form-string or stream operators and logical operators.

Comment: Thanks JHBonarius! I will use std::bitset when printing the number

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 0b01101
int b = 0b01001

int c = a & b;
```

You can convert a binary string to int like this:

```
std::string str = "1101";
int num = std::stoi("01010", 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I didn't offer the correct terms so this isn't exactly what I was looking for. The term I was missing is bitwise. I apologize! I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% what I was looking for, but it does do what I wanted. The one part I would say isn't to my expectation is that I convert the numbers to decimal rather than leaving everything in binary. Regardless... this does take in two binary numbers and outputs one binary number after ANDing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input1 = " ";
    string input2 = " ";

    cout << "Enter first binary number: " << endl;
    cin >> input1;

    cout << "Enter second binary number: " << endl;
    cin >> input2;

    int a = (int)bitset<64>(input1).to_ulong();
    cout << a << endl;

    int b = (int)bitset<64>(input2).to_ulong();
    cout << b << endl;

    int c = a & b;
    cout << c << endl;

    string output = bitset<8>(c).to_string();
    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;

}
```